# Linked list in IDA

Tags: ida, x86

I debug a program with IDA, it have a part of code that i don't understand

```
loc_8048E30:                            ; CODE XREF: phase_6+9Ej
.text:08048E30 mov     esi, [esi+8]
.text:08048E33 inc     ebx
.text:08048E34 cmp     ebx, eax
.text:08048E36 jl      short loc_8048E30
```

line 1: `mov esi, [esi+8]` when I debug address of esi is `0x804B260` so `esi+8` is `0x804B268`.

The value in `[esi+8]` is `60h` so after `mov esi, [esi+8]`, the value in `esi` is `60h` but it really is `0x804B260`. Why it is `0x804B260`?

And when esi is named .data:node2, it is linked link?

[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instruction `mov esi, [esi + 8]` copies **4 bytes** (DWORD) of data at the location pointed to by `esi + 8`to register `esi`.

In your case `esi` is `0804B260` so it copies **4 bytes** from `0804B268`. Since x86_64 is little endian the least significant byte as per the screenshot 1 is 0x60. The remaining three bytes are located below (not in the picture).

It is named `node2` as it is an exported symbol.